# python filter string only showing tags less than 2 words

Tags: python, count, if-statement

Trying to take a string of tags and only save the first 10 that only have less than 2 words. Don't know if this code is the right direction or not...

```
mystring = 'one, two, three, three three three, four four four, five, six'

for text in mystring:
    number = len(mystring.split())
        if text >= 2:

print number
```

basically want to output:
one, two three, five, six

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[item.strip() for item in mystring.split(',') if len(item.split()) < 2]
```

"The result of removing whitespace from either end, of each of those items resulting from splitting mystring on commas, which produces less than two sub-items if split on whitespace".

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> mystring = 'one, two, three, three three three, four four four, five, six'
# first separate the string into into a list and strip the extraneous spaces off..
>>> str_list = map(lambda s: s.strip(), mystring.split(','))
# then create a new list where the number of "numbers" in each list item are less or equal than two
>>> my_nums = filter(lambda s: len(s.split()) <= 2, str_list))
>>> print my_nums
['one', 'two', 'three', 'five', 'six']
```

Comment: this worked, only change the < to <= to get the ones with 2 words also.

Comment: well you said **less** than 2 words :)  But cool, I'm glad that worked out.

Answer (score 1):

a bit different ...

```
mystring = 'one, two, three, three three, four, five, six'

for text in mystring.split(","):
    number = len(text.strip().split()) #split by default does it by space, and strip removes spaces at both ends of the string
    if number < 2:
        #this string contains less than two words
        print text
```

first split by `,` and then for every do a another split but this time by space.

Comment: don't need the count, just the tags that are under 2 words.

Comment: well then just print my string ... answer changed

Comment: Still doesn't work.  You are looking at the length of `mystring` when you do the `split`.

Comment: and I also corrected another error and put a strip to remove white spaces.

Comment: yes that is fixed now and also addes .strip() to avoid extra spaces

Comment: There is no need to `.strip()` a string before `.split()`ting it on whitespace: `' x y '.split()` yields `['x', 'y']`. However, Python strings are immutable, so `.strip()` does not actually modify `text`, and thus you'd want to `.strip()` before outputting.